# Easy and quick way to jump into node.js library from command line?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying build up good habits and a robust understanding of node/javascript.

Great answers to questions often come from Stackoverflow-ers who have taken time to look closely at the source code. (No surprise there, right?)

So, I'm getting myself into the habit of always checking out the underlying source code (cavaet - just javascript source code now, maybe C in the future).

**Is there way from the command line (or with Node) to jump to the source-code of some object you are using?** That is quickly go to the right file and line here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/lib

**Any tips or built-in tools in Node.js I should check out?**

Thank you.

Comment: I often just do a `console.log(object.method.toString());` which simply prints the text of the function out, which is often good enough to learn about it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I just tried it with `console.log(util.pump.toString());` and it outputs the code, which matches the github code.  [https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L504](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L504)

Comment: @generalhenry Can you officially answer it with what you wrote in the comment? I like to mark an answer with the green check mark. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often just do a `console.log(object.method.toString());` which simply prints the text of the function out, which is often good enough to learn about it.